# Keep table rows based on a groupby Series

Tags: pandas

Trying to keep rows from a table that are unique to 'FEATUREID' where the 'AREA' is largest.

table:

```
       FEATUREID  COUNT      AREA    MIN    MAX  RANGE          MEAN  
0        -129226   1659   1493100  58441  60966   2525  59522.358650   
58940  940170467   1658   1492200  36659  45157   8498  40877.910133   
0        -129226  61540  55386000  56586  62291   5705  58709.266363
```

I can get the values for 'AREA' that are the max for each 'FEATUREID' with

```
table.groupby(['FEATUREID'])['AREA'].max()

FEATUREID
-129226        55386000
-129225        59676300
-129224       110445300
940170467     1492200
```

This is a Series that I think has FEATUREID for an index? I want to select the table rows that this Series identifies, but I'm not sure the best way to do this.

Comment: Sorry are you after `table.loc[table.groupby('FEATUREID')['AREA'].idxmax()]`?

Comment: the table has 314,390 records in it to begin with, I want it to have 256,645 records in the end.  The table.loc[] above returns 1,035,507 records, not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) rows and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('FEATUREID')['AREA'].nlargest(1).reset_index(level=0)
                                                 .rename(columns={0:'AREA'})
print df1
       FEATUREID      AREA
0        -129226  55386000
58940  940170467   1492200

print pd.merge(df, df1, on=['FEATUREID','AREA'])
   FEATUREID  COUNT      AREA    MIN    MAX  RANGE          MEAN
0  940170467   1658   1492200  36659  45157   8498  40877.910133
1    -129226  61540  55386000  56586  62291   5705  58709.266363
```

If you need `index`, it is more complicated:

```
df1 = df.groupby('FEATUREID')['AREA'].nlargest(1).reset_index()
                                     .rename(columns={0:'AREA', 'level_1': 'index'})
print df1
   FEATUREID  index      AREA
0    -129226      0  55386000
1  940170467  58940   1492200

df = pd.merge(df.reset_index(), df1, on=['FEATUREID','AREA', 'index']).set_index('index')
df.index.name = None
print df
       FEATUREID  COUNT      AREA    MIN    MAX  RANGE          MEAN
58940  940170467   1658   1492200  36659  45157   8498  40877.910133
0        -129226  61540  55386000  56586  62291   5705  58709.266363
```